# EF different mapping for an entity based on inheritance

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have two entities (tables) Action and ActionLog. The ActionLog is derived from  Action. I need to map entity Action to table Action when it is used alone and map it to table ActionLog when it is used inside an inheritance relationship.

### Entities:

Action entity properties:

- Action_Property1

  Action_Property2

  Action_Property3

ActionLog entity properties:

- All the inherited properties from Action entity

  ActionLog_Property1

### Tables:

Action table columns:

- Action_Property1

  Action_Property2

  Action_Property3

ActionLog table columns:

- Action_Property1

  Action_Property2

  Action_Property3

  ActionLog_Property1

Is this possible using EF6 Code First mapping in a single context?

## Edit 1:

I try to be more explicit. I need something like this:

```
using(var ctx = new DbContext())
{
    var action = new Action 
    { 
        Action_Property1 = 1,
        Action_Property2 = 2,
        Action_Property3 = 3
    };
    ctx.Actions.Add(action);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The lines above should write the Action entity to Action table.

```
using(var ctx = new DbContext())
{
    var actionLog = new ActionLog 
    { 
        Action_Property1 = 1,
        Action_Property2 = 2,
        Action_Property3 = 3,
        ActionLog_Property1 = 1
    };
    ctx.ActionLogs.Add(actionLog);
    ctx.SaveChanges();
}
```

The lines above should write the ActionLog entity to ActionLog table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. Using [Mapping the Table-Per-Concrete Class (TPC) Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//ef-EF/data/jj591617.aspx#2.6)
it can do so

```
public class InheritanceMappingContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Action> Action { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ActionLog> ActionLog { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ActionLog>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.MapInheritedProperties(); // add inherited property to actionLog
            m.ToTable("ActionLog");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Action>().Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("Action");
        });            
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, this was my first guess too. But after testing it, entity framework seems to be trying to use ActionLog table for both Action entity and ActionLog entity too. For example, when I try to add a new Action in my migration's seed method, it tells me that it cannot add it, because of a non-nullable column in the ActionLog table.

Comment: which tables was created in bd after init context? Do the tables have the correct structure column?

Comment: I am using manual migrations in the project. The lastest migration created a the ActionLog table and didn't try to remove the Action table. The only thing I noticed, however, it tried to remove all the foreign keys and indexes on Action table.

Comment: You were right, I created a clean project from scratch. It seems to be working in that.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, map your base class:

```
public class YourBaseClassMapping<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : YourBaseClassEntity
{
    protected YourBaseClassMapping()
    {
        HasKey(x => x.Id);
        ...
    }
}
```

and then map inherited class:

```
public class InheritedClassMapping<T> : EntityTypeConfiguration<T> where T : InheritedClassMapping
{
    public InheritedClassMapping()
    {
        // new mapping for inherited class
    }        
}
```

and add both mappings to DbModelBuilder as other mappings:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new YourBaseClassMapping());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new InheritedClassMapping());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I was more asking for how to tell entity framework to use a different mapping for the same entity based on the inheritance scenario it is involved in.

Comment: I edited the answer based on that, I believe that should work as you'd need to.

Comment: Can you fill the part, how would you remap ActionLog inherited properties in the way explained in the question? What would you use TPH, TPC? Becuase none of them seems to work.